# How to open localhost from any device but without use ngrok?

Tags: php, apache, tunnel

When we install

https://ngrok.com/

any device connect perfectlly to my PC in port 80 using localhost (Apache + PHP).

Now,
I need to get the same result but without use/install [NGROK]
and without modify the OTHERS devices (movil, PCs, MAC, ...)

I am in Windows 7 + Apache

Any help please?

PD:
( All this procediment is called TUNNEL ??? )

Comment: What's wrong with ngrok?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The "best" option would be to open a port in your firewall/modem and point it to your machine. If you don't have access to that device, it's much much harder (if not impossible), which is why ngrok is the better option.

Comment: thanks, I no have problem with [NGROK] samplely I want
"learn" what files edit/create and commands requireds
to access from any device.